# Arduino control 6 solenoid valves with different patterns

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on a project that requires to control 6 solenoid valves. I decided to use arduino to achieve this. My project requires me to open/close any number of this valves with different timings. For example one pattern might be that valves 1,2,3 are open for 2.5 seconds while valves 4,5,6 are closed, and then valves 4,5,6 are open for 2.5 while 1,2,3 are closed and so on. Now I got stuck when I tried to implement a functionality where I can choose different patterns using the IR remote. I am not sure how can I adjust the timings and make them synchronized in mid run. Here is the code that I wrote so far. On the bottom of the code you can see an example that I used to get the pattern that I mentioned above. chooseOption variable is intended to be used to choose which pattern of opening/closing valves will be performed.

```
#include <IRremote.h>
int input_pin = 28; //set D10 as input signal pin
IRrecv irrecv(input_pin);
decode_results signals;

class Flasher
{

  public:
  Flasher(int pin, long on, long off)
  {
  ledPin = pin;
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);     

  OnTime = on;
  OffTime = off;

  ledState = LOW; 
  previousMillis = 0;

  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }


  void setTimes(long newOn, long newOff);



  void Update()
  {
    // check to see if it's time to change the state of the LED
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if((ledState == LOW) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime))
    {
      ledState = HIGH;  // Turn it off
      previousMillis = currentMillis;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);  // Update the actual LED
    }
    else if ((ledState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime))
    {
      ledState = LOW;  // turn it on
      previousMillis = currentMillis;   // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);   // Update the actual LED
    }
  }



  private:
  int ledPin;    
  long OnTime;  
  long OffTime;   


  int ledState;              
  unsigned long previousMillis;   

};

void Flasher::setTimes(long newOn, long newOff)
{
  OffTime = newOff;
  OnTime = newOn;
}




 unsigned long time;



 int onT = 2500;
 int offT = 2500;


  //Flasher led1(portNo, OnTime, OffTime)
Flasher led1(22, onT, offT);
Flasher led2(23, onT, offT);
Flasher led3(24, onT, offT);
Flasher led4(25, onT, offT);
Flasher led5(26, onT, offT);
Flasher led6(27, onT, offT);


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // enable input from IR receiver
}


int chooseOption =0;

void loop()
{

time = millis();

    if (irrecv.decode(&signals)) 
    {
      if(signals.value == 0x9716BE3F)
      {
        chooseOption = 1;

      }
      else if(signals.value == 0x3D9AE3F7)
      {
        chooseOption = 2;

      }

      irrecv.resume(); // get the next signal
    }

 //So here for example I can do something like


if(time > 5000)
  {
    led1.Update();
    led3.Update();
    led5.Update();

  }
  if(time >7500)
{
     led2.Update();
     led4.Update();
     led6.Update();


//and pumps 1 3 and 5 are on for 2.5 secs and then pumps 2,4 and 6 are on and so on. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your program should be like this:

```
//(I don't explain IRremote implementations, since yours is good)
#define xor(a,b) (( a && (!b)) || ((!a) && b))
#define n_ports 6 //not to waste memory
#define input_pin 28
byte ports[n_ports] = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27}; //you can also use int if you prefer
int i=0; // counter variable
bool b_pattern[7]; 

void setup() {
  for(i=0;i<n_ports;i++)
    pinMode(ports[i], OUTPUT);
  //IRremote initialization
}

void loop() {
  time = millis();

  //(IRremote implementations)

  switch(chooseOption) { //for different patterns
    case 0:  //here some examples
      time = time%5000;//notice the "time%5000": it's to get 5 seconds periods, you can set it as you want
      b_pattern[0] = time<2500; //that's a weird boolean, shall be the same as HIGH and LOW
      //if it doesnt work, just put an if construct
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        digitalWrite(ports[i], b_pattern[0] ); 
      for(;i<6;i++) //yes, I'm ignoring n_ports checking *_*
        digitalWrite(ports[i], !b_pattern[0] );
    break;
    case 1:
      time = time%5000;
      b_pattern[0] = time<1666; // 1/3 of 5 second-pattern
      b_pattern[1] = time<2500; // 1/2
      b_pattern[2] = time<3333; // 2/3
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        digitalWrite(ports[i], xor(b_pattern[0], b_pattern[2]) );
      for(;i<4;i++)
        digitalWrite(ports[i], !xor(b_pattern[0], b_pattern[2]) );
      for(;i<6;i++)
        digitalWrite(ports[i], b_pattern[1]);
    break;
    case 2:
      time = time%6000;
      b_pattern[0] = time<1000;
      b_pattern[1] = time<1500;
      b_pattern[2] = time<2000;
      b_pattern[3] = time<3000;
      b_pattern[4] = time<4000;
      b_pattern[5] = time<4500;
      b_pattern[6] = time<5000; //VERY weird but logic, let's simplify
      b_pattern[1] = xor(b_pattern[1], xor(b_pattern[3], b_pattern[5]));
      b_pattern[0] = xor(xor(xor(b_pattern[0], b_pattern[2]),xor(b_pattern[3], b_pattern[4])), b_pattern[6]);
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        digitalWrite( ports[i], b_pattern[1]);
      for(;i<6;i++)
        digitalWrite( ports[i], b_pattern[0]);
    break;
  }
}
```

To change the triggered ports group, change the order in **ports** array. I also suggest you to check the program first with leds.